# SSH from mac to linux -> start gnome-session -> X11 keyboard mapping all messed up

Tags: linux, macos, keyboard, gnome, xorg

I have 2 computers: echo.local is running Ubuntu 9.04.  justin.local is running Mac OS 10.6.1. X11 version on the mac is 2.3.4.

I open X11 on the mac, and open a new xterm window (Applications Menu -> Terminal), everything is fine. Keyboard works as expected.

I do `ssh -X echo.local` from the mac (connecting to the linux box), and from the linux command prompt, start xterm -  everything is fine.  Keyboard works as expected.

I do `gnome-session` from the linux command prompt (through SSH), gnome launches, but keyboard mapping is ALL types of screwed up.  If I kill gnome-session and open an xterm via ssh, keyboard mapping is still screwed up.   If I then kill the SSH session entirely, and do X11 -> Applications Menu -> Terminal, opening a brand new xterm window on the mac with no SSH session running at all ... keyboard mapping is still screwed up.

Only after I quit X11 and relaunch, is the keyboard mapping back to normal.

Keyboard layout under GNOME is Apple->MacBook/MacBook Pro.

Comment: Justin - that answer worked for me, can you perhaps mark it as the correct answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try creating a xmodmap first:

sudo xmodmap -pke > .xmodmaprc

After that, ssh -X  gconf-editor

Navigate to:

> Desktop > Gnome > Peripherals > Keyboard

Select "layout" and then add "us".

Restart X11

... This is half me fooling around, and the other half blatantly stolen from 
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/feisty/+source/vino/+bug/112955/comments/31

I'm not sure if the .xmodmaprc needs to be created, but hey.. the above steps worked for me!

Andrew